# Accessing property from an array of records in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a route defined like this:

```
Route::get('/buyer_home', function(){
$senders = \App\Message::where(['to' => \Auth::guard('web_buyer')->user()->username])->distinct()->get(['from']);
$sellers = array();
foreach ($senders as $sender) {
    $sellers[] = \App\Seller::where('email', $sender->from)->get();
}
  return view('buyer.home', compact('sellers', 'senders'));
});
```

I am in a situation where I need to access the columns/properties of the `sellers` table/model in my view to establish a condition like this: `@if(sender->from == seller->email)`. But I am getting

> Property [email] does not exist on this collection instance.

error message when I try to access the `email` property of each of the `sellers` result within a `@foreach` loop. My intention is to pass the list of the `sellers` to the view, and only those sellers who have the email that matches the `email` returned from `$sender->from`. How do I tackle this?

**EDIT:**

This is the snippet of my view code where the error is thrown:

```
<div class="list-group">
    @foreach($sellers as $seller)

       <a href="#" class="list-group-item">From: {{ $seller->email }}</a>

    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Could you point in your code where it throws this error?

Comment: "collection instance" makes me think that you are trying to access the email property on an object that is a Laravel Collection object, and not a specific Seller model object. But I agree with @FelippeDuarte, we need to see more of your code,specifically the line where you are getting this error

Comment: Hi, @FelippeDuarte and victor, I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem.

`$sellers` is an array of collections. You should replace the way you query with `whereIn`

```
$emails = array_map(function($s) {
    return $s->from;
}), $senders);
$sellers = \App\Seller::whereIn('email', $emails)->get();
```

Another way would be to replace in your view:

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">From: {{ $seller[0]->email }}</a>
```